# create std::string from char* in a safe way

Tags: c++, exception

I have a `char* p`, which points to a `\0`-terminated string. How do I create a C++ `string` from it in an exception-safe way?

Here is an unsafe version:

```
string foo()
{
  char *p = get_string();

  string str( p );
  free( p );
  return str;
}
```

An obvious solution would be to try-catch - any easier ways?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `shared_ptr` from [C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or [Boost](http://www.boost.org/libs/smart_ptr/):

```
string
foo()
{
    shared_ptr<char> p(get_string(), &free);
    string str(p.get());
    return str;
}
```

This uses a very specific feature of `shared_ptr` not available in `auto_ptr` or anything else, namely the ability to specify a custom deleter; in this case, I'm using `free` as the deleter.

Comment: yes, except that we don't normally use Boost, but I can create such a class myself. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Can I ask you what exception you are expecting in your example?

On many platforms (Linux, AIX) new or malloc will never fail and your app will get killed by the os if you run out of memory.

See this link: [What happens when Linux runs out of memory.](http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2006/11/30/linux-out-of-memory.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yup - stack-based unwinding. Modern C++ Design has the general solution but in this case you can use

```
struct Cleanup {
        void* toFree;
        Cleanup(void* toFree) : toFree(toFree) {}
        ~Cleanup() { free(toFree); }
    private:
        Cleanup(Cleanup&);
        void operator=(Cleanup&);
};
```

No matter what happens with your std::string, free(toFree) will be called when your Cleanup object goes out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `p` does not point to a 0-terminated string if `get_string()` returns NULL; that's the problem here, since the `std::string` constructors that take a pointer to 0-terminated C string cannot deal with NULL, which is as much a 0-terminated C string as two dozens of bananas are.

So, if `get_string()` is your own function, as opposed to a library function, then maybe you should make sure that it cannot return NULL. You could for instance let it return the sought `std::string` itself, since it knows it's own state. Otherwise, I'd do this, using the `Cleanup` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246445/create-stdstring-from-char-in-a-safe-way#246460) as a helper to guarantee that `p` cannot leak (as suggested by Martin York in a comment):

```
string foo()
{
    const char* p = get_string();
    const Cleanup cleanup(p);
    const std::string str(p != NULL ? p : "");

    return str;
}
```

Comment: Apart from the code does not compile (Look at L""). Its not exception safe. You dont guarantee that p will be released.

Comment: Ah! Sorry about that - I only develop for Windows CE based devices, and there we only have Unicode strings, so the 'L' prefix is hammered into my spine when I write code. That case is now fixed.

Comment: Phew! Now that leak is gone also. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

We commonly use [ScopeGuard](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184403758) for these cases:

```
string foo()
{
  char *p = get_string();
  ScopeGuard sg = MakeGuard(&free, p);
  string str( p );
  return str;
}
```